# Chevron symbol (>) not mapped correctly after adding a new keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

On French Azerty keyboard, the key on the right of "maj" is the chevron "<" (with maj activated, ">"). I think the key name is `<LGST>`

If I add an English keyboard configuration and set it as first configuration (not the active configuration, but the first configuration), then 
With English active, this same key does a "\" (maj "|")
With French active, this same key also results in this symbol, "\", instead of the expected "<"

I did not find other keys causing this problem

Why would the send character be affected by which configuration is first? And how to solve that?
Easy solution : put the French configuration first
BUT, I have to keep the English configuration in order for Wine application to correctly understand the 123... keys (which are special characters &é" in French)

On Ubuntu 18.04 with Cinnamon 3.6.7 environment. 
I choose keyboard configuration using cinnamon "parameter" gui

Comment: It sounds weird, and I couldn't reproduce it on my Ubuntu 19.10. Btw, I suppose you are talking about the _English (UK)_ layout, not just any English layout.

Comment: Yes it is English (UK) and French. (Nothing in the parenthesis after French)